# Size of data in secondary exceeded primary after the initial resync in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-replication, data-synchronization

I step down the primary node, deleted its data and performed the initial resync from new primary. But when i checked the size of data after the completion of initial resync, I found that the size of data in this node was 409G whereas size of data in other node from where this node has synced its data was 326G. Hence the size was increased by 83G after the resync.

Earlier also i have done such initial resync, and every time I have found that the size of data decreases after the resync.
But in this case its opposite.

Recently I have upgraded the version of cluster from 2.4.9 to 2.6.7. This was my first initial resync after the version upgrade. Is this because of the new MongoDB version.

Did anyone come across this kind of issue.

Comment: A little off-topic here. This should rather go to http://dba.stackexchange.com Interesting question, though. I did a resync a couple of times to reproduce the problem, but I can't.

Comment: Thanks @MarkusWMahlberg. I also re synced the same node twice from scratch but faced same issue in both the cases. I have posted this question to the dba.stackexchange.com . The link is http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96962/size-of-data-in-secondary-exceeded-primary-after-its-initial-resync-from-primary

Comment: So please delete it here.